# Linq to sql to return related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two models which are related.

```
public class RolesModels
{
    public RolesModels()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<UserModels>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 6 characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Caption")]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can Create")]
    public bool createRole { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can View")]
    public bool viewRole { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Can Modify")]
    public bool modifyRole { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can Delete")]
    public bool deleteRole { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserModels> Users { get; set; }

}
```

and the second is like this

```
   public class UserModels
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int user_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 3 characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string user_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 4 characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string user_pass { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 6 characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Registeration Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enable User")]
    public bool status { get; set; }

    //[Bindable(false)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Roles")]
    public virtual RolesModels Roles { get; set; }

}
```

The thing is, I want to be able to retrieve records with the following columns:

```
   User Name | Email | Registration Date | Enable User | Role Caption
```

here is my linq to sql code:

```
  var model = from c in db.UserModels
               join o in db.RolesModels on c.RoleId equals o.RoleId
               where 1==1
               select c;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using the Consoto University sample project.
Here is the solution:

```
var m = db.UserModels.Include(u => u.Roles);
return View(m.ToList());
```

and modelItem => item.Roles.Caption to fetch the role caption from the Roles models using the navigational property.

Thanks all for the attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `where 1=1` part, because it gives you always true and does not affect result set. Also you already have navigation property for roles, so you don't need to join entities manually:

```
from u in db.UserModels
select new { 
  UserName = user_name,
  Email = UserEmail,
  RegistrationDate = RegDate,
  EnableUser = status,
  RoleCaption = u.Roles.Caption
}
```

Consider also to do null-check if it is possible that user can not have role assigned.

Comment: Aren't you missing a comparison?

Comment: @Silvermind no, I don't think comparison makes sense this query

Comment: Edit: sorry you hadn't finished your answer and I didn't read it properly ;)

Comment: it generate the following syntax error in the line from r in u.Roles

An expression of type'ApplicationName.Models.RolesModels' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ApplicationName.Models.UserModels>'. Type inference in the call to 'SelectMany'

Comment: @Wale sorry, was mislead by Roles property name (thought it contains collection of roles, but actually it holds single role), updated code now

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy, thanks. Pardon my ignorance as i am new to MVC. This seem fine except that my view has IEnumerable dictionary and the result of the query seem to be string. I added ToList method and another error is generated.

Comment: @Wale no, result of query will be sequence of anonymous objects which have properties UserName, Email, RegistrationDate, EnableUser and RoleCaption. You can add condition `RoleCaption = u.Roles == null ? null : u.Roles.Caption` to handle case when user has null role

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy, still the same. I think it has to do with the type of object received by the view (string) as compared to the expected object type (IEnumerable).

Comment: @Wale this query does not returns string

Answer (score 0):

You mean like This

```
var model = from c in db.UserModels
               join o in db.RolesModels on c.RoleId equals o.RoleId
               where 1==1
               select new { c.user_name, c.UserEmail, c.RegDate, o.Caption,  c.status}).ToList();
```

Comment: I get an error using the above. An error based on dictionary type. I used IEnumerable in my view. How do I correct this?

Comment: without ToList it yield string error. Saying string was was passed instead of a model.

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = (from c in db.UserModels.AsEnumerable()
               join o in db.RolesModels.AsEnumerable() on c.RoleId equals o.RoleId
               select new { c.user_name, c.UserEmail, c.RegDate, o.Caption,  c.status}).ToList();
```

Do something like this.